# how to connect data from a drop down list to data from a input text in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

Say I have this problem using forms

```
<form name = "card">
    Your Card's Number: <input type="text" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX'" id = "card_num"/></br>
</form>     

    Type of Credit Card:
    <select id = "typeCard">
    <option value="none" selected="selected">-- choose one --</option>
    <option>Visa</option>
    <option>Master</option>
    <option>JCB</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "button" value = "Validate" onclick = "validateCard()">
```

this is my html code i want to get the value of the credit card number in order to validate it using javascript

```
    function validateCard()
{

    var card = document.getElementById("typeCard").value;
    var cardNum = document.getElementById("card_num").value;
    document.write(cardNum);    

    if (card === "Visa")
    {
        alert("hey");
    }

    else if (card ==="Master")
    {
        alert("hoy");
    }

    else if (card ==="JBC")
    {
        alert("hoy");
    }
}
```

this is my javascript code it doesn't work with the

```
var cardNum = document.getElementById("card_num").value;
    document.write(cardNum);
```

code, can anyone help me I've googled it, but I can't have any solutions.

Comment: Never use `document.write` once the document has been loaded.

Comment: I'm just using it so that i will know if i got the value of cardNum

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Are you saying cardNum doesn't hold the correct value or no value at all? What is the incorrect value you're seeing?

Comment: @joeltine cardNum has no value at all

Comment: Are you expecting the value to be "XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" on first click? If so, the placeholder value won't be accessible through "elem.value". I created http://jsfiddle.net/p5eyxkv4/ as an example and if I type something in the input and click "Validate"... the console shows the correct value.

Comment: No sir i know how to handle placeholders i need two outputs the card number ang its type. i will use the card number later in the if else statements.

Comment: Well there's some other issue here. What you have should work. Is your JavaScript executing before the DOM is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Where does your script come from? It may not loaded at the point you are binding click event handler. So you better use

```
document.getElementById('validateBtn').addEventListener('click', validateCard, null);
```

in the code. Also don't use document.write. I have created working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dbj7qanr/1/).

Comment: sir im supposed to have 2 values 1st the value of the card number and what type of card. For example 1234 5678 1234 5123 Visa.

Comment: It's working on the demo but when i copied it in my own document to run it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the developer console. It may point out if there any errors. You have to remove that onclick event handler from the validate button.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null  this is what the console said. what should i do??

Comment: Did you add id attribute to the validate button. tag should be something like `<input id="validateBtn" type = "button" value = "Validate"/>`

Comment: wrap that javascript code with window.onload event if you using script inside head tag. other than that you can load your javascript just above the closing body tag. I have no idea how you use javascript with the html page. This is my whole [html page](http://pastebin.com/YYczS1db)

Comment: window.onload = function() solves the problem for me sir thank you!! i have another question does the cardNum value a string or object??

Comment: It is a string. You can use typeof operator to find the type of a variable. eg: `console.log(typeof cardNum);`

Answer (score 0):

I wish .value worked normally on selects :P
Try this:

```
var card = document.getElementById("typeCard").options[document.getElementById("typeCard").selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: still got the same problem it has no response, i think cardNum has no value at all.

Comment: @RamAquino Actually...running just the code that you give in the question, I get a response in Chrome, so...not sure where your issue is, unless you have additional code.

Comment: Yeah it's working for me getting the type of the card but not the card no itself.

Comment: @RamAquino I got the card number, too though...

Actually...how exactly are you running the document? On the web or on your own computer? And what is the file being saved as?

Comment: im running it on my computer, the file is being saved as .html